# show bluetooth Le devices on baseAdapter

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, baseadapter

I have created an adapter to show the scanned devices in my Custom Dialog. The custom dialog appears but even after none of the devices appears.
Whenever I check the logcat there are devices present from Bluetooth Le Scanner.
The code for the custom dialog is below

```
public class CustomDialog extends Dialog{

    private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private boolean mScanning;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private AppCompatButton Scan;
    private AppCompatButton Stop;
    Context mContext;
    TextView textStatus;
    BluetoothLeScanner mLeScanner;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    // Stops scanning after 10 seconds.
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 10000;
    ProgressBar contentLoadingProgressBar;


    public CustomDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

        contentLoadingProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.contentLoading);
        contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textStatus = findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        textStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Scan = (AppCompatButton) findViewById(R.id.scanButton);

        Scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Scan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                BlueteethManager.with(getContext()).scanForPeripherals(10000, blueteethDevices -> {
                    for (BlueteethDevice device : blueteethDevices) {
                        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(device.getBluetoothDevice().getName())) {
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                            mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            Timber.d("%s - %s", device.getName(), device.getMacAddress());

                        }
                    }
                    contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    textStatus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Scan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                });
            }
        });


        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();


    }



    // Adapter for holding devices found through scanning.
    private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<BlueteethDevice> mLeDevices;
        private LayoutInflater mInflator;

        public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
            super();
            mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BlueteethDevice>();
            mInflator = getLayoutInflater();
        }

        public void addDevice(BlueteethDevice device) {
            if (!mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
                mLeDevices.add(device);
            }
        }

        public void clear() {
            mLeDevices.clear();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mLeDevices.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return mLeDevices.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            CustomDialog.viewHolder viewHolder;
            // General ListView optimization code.
            if (view == null) {
                   view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
                viewHolder = new CustomDialog.viewHolder();
                viewHolder.cardDevice=view.findViewById(R.id.cardDevice);
                viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
                viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (CustomDialog.viewHolder) view.getTag();


            }

            BlueteethDevice device = mLeDevices.get(i);
            final String deviceName = device.getName();

            if (deviceName != null && deviceName.length() > 0)
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
            else
                viewHolder.deviceName.setText("Unknown Device");
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getMacAddress());
            viewHolder.deviceAddress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    device.connect(true, isConnected -> {
                        Timber.d("Is the peripheral connected? %s", Boolean.toString(isConnected));
                        if (isConnected){
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "BLE device Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            textStatus.setText("Connected");
                            textStatus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Scan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to connect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            return view;
        }
    }


    static class viewHolder {
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
        CardView cardDevice;
    }
}
```

I am using a third party library for scanning devices. It works correctly though but didn't get any of the device name or address appears on the custom dialog. does the Layout Inflator cause problems to me or what.